# Cannot run protractor for testing against angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor

I have been working on automated testing for one of our Angular projects, approx 1 month ago all was showing hopeful using protractor. In that time we have upgraded to visual studio 2015 and switched to a different user account and all seems to have failed.

I enter my solution and run `npm update` to download all the modules, I then have ran `npm install -g protractor`, this was failing at first and after much research i found out that `node-gyp` did not play well with VS2015 and i had to change my environment variables to make it use 2013. `npm install -g protractor` now worked, but upon attempting to use `protractor --version` i get the message returned `'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` What is going on? Is this a windows 10/Visual studio 2015 issue?

Comment: what version of npm & node are you using? Also can you tell where your node_modules are getting installed? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try `node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor --version`?